# Issue with bitbucket repository to deploy rails app using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bitbucket, rvm-capistrano

Getting `github` for `bitbucket` repository.

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (some_ip_address)' can't be established.

This is my deploy file. `deploy:setup` and `deploy:check` are working perfectly.

```
require "bundler/capistrano" 
require "rvm/capistrano"

default_run_options[:pty] = true 
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :repository, 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git' 
set :scm :git 
set :scm_verbose, true
set :user, 'root'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :migrate_target, :current
set :branch, 'master'
set :application, 'my_app_name' 
set :domain, 'my_domain_ip_address'
set :applicationdir, "/home/deploy/domains/#{application}"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/domains/#{application}"
role :web, domain role :app, domain role :db,  domain, :primary => true
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :system

after 'deploy:restart', 'deploy:cleanup'

namespace :deploy do   
  task :start do ; end   
  task :stop do ; end   
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod 777 #{File.join(current_path,'tmp/')}"
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod 777 #{File.join(current_path,'log/')}"
  end
  task :after_deploy do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle install --deployment"
    run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake db:migrate"
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod 777 -R #{current_path}/tmp/"
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod 777 -R #{current_path}/log/"
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod 777 . #{current_path}/log/"   
  end 
end

after 'deploy', 'deploy:after_deploy'
```

Note: I am trying to deploy rails app for first time.

`Server: Digital Ocean VPS`

`Repository: bitbucket.org`

I added `ssh key` of `server` in the `bitbucket` account.

Issue: While `'cap:deploy'`, after executing `deploy,deploy:update,deploy:update_code,deploy:finalize_update,deploy:assets:symlink,`

Getting issue at executing `'bundle install'`, It is asking for `github` authenticity, while am using `bitbucket`.

Comment: Since it's already running `bundle install` chances are your code has already been pulled successfully. Do you have any gem that you're linking to github repo instead of rubygems.org?

Comment: yes code was deployed and it is asking authenticity from github, which i don't have and dont need.

If i press ctlr+c there, it is removing the release and more over there is no 'current' folder created.

Comment: There is one gem referring to github.

Comment: well as I said… if there is a gem pointing to github repo then ofcourse you need to add github to knownhost

Comment: actually, I added ssh key from server into one my github account.

Comment: Hey, error changed after changing github related gems. But got different error.This time it is for rvm_path

`failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm/ /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd -- /home/deploy/domains/app_name/releases/20130910084427 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile'" on domain_ip_address`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the `git URL` like this

```
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git'
```

If you have not added your `keys` to bitbucket, you can do it here `https://bitbucket.org/account/user/username/ssh-keys/`

Comment: When i try that i am getting this error.

`Command git ls-remote ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git master returned status code pid 5264 exit 128`

Comment: Have you added your ssh keys to bitbucket?

Comment: yes i have added to bitbucket and as well as to github. I am not getting error now. After following first comment from  j03w. Now am getting error for rvm_path. I will try that thing.

`failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm/ /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd -- /home/deploy/domains/app_name/releases/20130910084427 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile'" on domain_ip_address`